Model Derivatives in Design Automation
i am facing issue in extracting meta data like levels ,doors etc. of the uploaded model in Design Automation Revit. Can anyone help me with this.
try {
const urn = await getObjectId(bucketKey, inputFileNameOSS, req);
const urnBase64 = Buffer.from(urn).toString('base64');

        const clientId = '2gQaF4eUXh5iRhh4wQ5PFzBwTNTocP8GRdq3o7XvVmilvhBZ';
        const clientSecret = '**************************';
        
        const url = `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/${urn}/metadata`;        
        const headers = {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${req.oauth_token.access_token}`,
        };
      
        const response = await axios.get(url, { headers });
        console.log('Metadata response:', response.data);
      
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          // Server responded with a status code outside 2xx
          console.error('Error response data:', error.response.data);
          console.error('Status code:', error.response.status);
        } else if (error.request) {
          // No response received from server
          console.error('No response received:', error.request);
        } else {
          // Other errors (e.g., misconfiguration, request setup)
          console.error('Error message:', error.message);
        }
      } 

i have tried this code im getting 40 error/ axios error
